# How can I move back data from external SD card to internal memory?

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, sd-card, android-10

Today I added an sd card to my smartphone (Fairphone 3+, Android 10), I selected to use it as internal storage, and moved the photos and some apps (don't know which ones) to it automatically. After the move, I now cannot see any of my photos (except a dozen of them) and some apps (like Dropbox) keep crashing. Stupidly enough, I didn't back it up. Now the camera doesn't show any photo, the files application doesn't show them, if I connect to a PC, I get an error trying to open the DCIM folder, and the SD card cannot be opened by other devices (there's no warning of it when selecting). The space is however marked as occupied in the setttings

How can I move back this data from the external SD card to the internal memory?

Comment: Are you sure the SD-card was genuine? A lot of extra large SD-cards for cheap money are fake cards that have may be 16GB real storage but claim they have 256GB or more. So if you write to them data loss is inevitable.

Comment: @Robert it was a 256GB SanDisk bought off Amazon, and was definitely not cheap. I would be very surprised if it was not genuine

Comment: so what happen behind the scenes when formatting as internal, SD Card is repartitioned and encrypted, ext4 partition is mounted */data/media/0 > /mnt/expand/\** and symlinked */sdcard > /storage/emulated/0*. former "Internal storage" in */data/media* is now unused (disk space might still occupied). you can *'adb pull /storage/emulated/0'* to backup files from adopted SD Card once, eject, and *'adb pull /storage/emulated/0'* again to backup files from internal storage. in case you have root access you can get encryption key from */data/misc/vold* and decrypt SD Card on PC (for direct access)